# django - creating an instance of a model by looping through all fields and assigning a value

Tags: django, models

Suppose I have this model `Person` with these attributes: `foo1`, `foo2` and `foo3`

Can you do something like this?

```
fields = ['foo1', 'foo2', 'foo3']

p = Person()

for field in fields:
    p.field = 5

p.save()
```

Comment: This can be done using the built-in [`setattr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#setattr) function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*some explanation at the request of ADM*

You have list of model fields for changing in fields list. For multiple assigning, python has built_in function setattr
https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#setattr
After setting all values for field you have to call model method `save` to save new values into the db.

```
fields = ['foo1', 'foo2', 'foo3']

p = Person()

for field in fields:
    setattr(p, field, 5)

p.save()
```

Comment: Add some explanation to your answer.